# View-based NSTableView is only redrawn when focus is changed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, appkit, reloaddata

I'm writing a simple Cocoa app with GUI that only consists of a simple table whose data may update sometimes. But when data actually updates, table's rows in most cases disappear completely. But as soon as I change focus (click on desktop if my app's a primary window or click on app's window if it's not), everything shows up properly

Data is handled in a separate singleton class that runs a thread that actually looks after data source and publishes NSNotification when data changes. Window controller receives that notification, extracts new data and triggers `[tableView reloadData]` - that's where the problems begin

Window controller is a data source and delegate for the table and implements `numberOfRowsInTableView` method and `viewForTableColumn` method. When the problem occurs, `numberOfRowsInTableView` is called and returns non-zero value, but `viewForTableColumn` isn't called at all

I expect the table to be properly redrawn whenever `[tableView reloadData]` is called and wherever my focus is, but on practice everything just disappears and properly redrawn only after I change focus

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The problem was updating GUI from background thread